# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object in ajaxcontroltoolkit?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have coded as shown below and also I have included TargetControlID in MaskedEditExtender Tag but I am getting as NullReferenceException:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Register.aspx.cs" Inherits="Employee_Managment.Register" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="../Styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>


         <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1" EnableScriptGlobalization="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <%--<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="autocompletetest"></asp:TextBox>
        <ajax:AutoCompleteExtender runat="server" EnableCaching="false" CompletionInterval="10" MinimumPrefixLength="2" CompletionSetCount="3" TargetControlID="autocompletetest" ServiceMethod="NamePick" FirstRowSelected="false"></ajax:AutoCompleteExtender>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="label"></asp:Label>--%>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>        
        <ajax:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender2" runat="server" MaskType="None" Mask="9999" TargetControlID="TextBox3">
        </ajax:MaskedEditExtender>
        <%--<ajax:MaskedEditValidator ID="MaskedEditValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox3" ControlExtender="MaskedEditExtender2" Display="Dynamic" IsValidEmpty="false" InvalidValueMessage="Invalid date!" EmptyValueMessage="The date is not entered">
        </ajax:MaskedEditValidator>   --%>


</body>
</html>
```

I am getting error as shown below:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   AjaxControlToolkit.MaskedEditExtender.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +183
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +131
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2952
```

Kindly comment the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the below code...this is working for me..

I have set the same id for maskededit extender and masked edit validator's controlextender ( Here my id of maskededitextender is MaskedEditExtender1 and i have set the same id for Maskededitvalidator ControlExtender)

```
 <asp:TextBox id="txtStartTime" runat="server" placeholder="HH:mm" OnTextChanged="txtStartTime_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" ></asp:TextBox>
                             <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender1" runat="server"
    AcceptAMPM="false" Mask="99:99" CultureAMPMPlaceholder="" CultureCurrencySymbolPlaceholder=""
    CultureDateFormat="" CultureDatePlaceholder="" CultureDecimalPlaceholder=""
    CultureThousandsPlaceholder="" CultureTimePlaceholder="" Enabled="True"
    MaskType="Time" TargetControlID="txtStartTime" />
                             <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditValidator ID="MaskedEditValidator4" runat="server"
                 ControlExtender="MaskedEditExtender1"
                 ControlToValidate="txtStartTime"
                 IsValidEmpty="True"
                 EmptyValueMessage="Time is required"
                InvalidValueMessage="Time is invalid"
                 Display="Dynamic"
                 TooltipMessage="Input a time"
                 EmptyValueBlurredText="Invalid Time"
                 InvalidValueBlurredMessage="Invalid Time" />
```